# Harmonic L2-Forms

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, harmonic-functions

Let $(M,g)$ be a geodesically-complete Riemannian manifold. It is well-known that every harmonic $L^{2}$-function on $M$ is necessarily constant. The way to prove this is to show that every harmonic $L^{2}$-function is both closed and co-closed and every closed function has to be a constant (lets assume $M$ is connected).

My question is the following:

> If $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ be harmonic such that $df$ is $L^{2}$. Does it then also follow that $f$ is constant?

My first approach was

$$\infty>\Vert df\Vert_{L^{2}}^{2}=\langle d f,df\rangle_{L^{2}}=\langle f,\Delta f\rangle_{L^{2}}=0$$

and hence $df=0$. However, I am not sure about the last to last step, since one need somehow a $L^{2}$-version of Stokes theorem.

Comment: I don't understand your discussion in the first paragraph.  What do you mean by saying "every harmonic $L^2$ function is both closed and co-closed"?  Is the proof not exactly what you've put as your trial proof?

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter if we already knew $df=0$, then it is easy to conclude, but the issue is the second equal sign, where Stokes’ theorem was used. This is unjustified a-priori since $M$ could be non-compact.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter thats clear. My point is that deriving df=0 uses stokes theorem and this ins non trivial for non compact manifolds and L2 functions

Comment: @TedShifrin the proof is perfectly fine in the compact case yes. In the non compact case however not, since my derivation needs stokes theorem for L2 functions.